# Overriding an ActiveRecord attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model with a completed:boolean column that I'd like override so I can add some conditional code.

I've never override an ActiveRecord attribute before and wanted to know if the method below is good practice?

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def completed=(b)
    write_attribute(:completed, b)
    # IF b is true then do something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is fine. The method you've suggested is the one described in the [ActiveRecord documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) (scroll down to the heading **Overwriting default accessors**)

One thing I would add however, is that depending on the specifics of your circumstances you may be able to achieve what you're after using a [before_save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#M002139) callback as an alternative.

Comment: I would use `self[:completed] = b` rather than `write_attribute`, it just feels neater.

Comment: Yep, ActiveRecord's `[]` and `[]=` are just wrappers around `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` respectively so use whichever feels more natural to you.